# How do I get dissociated from a question I dislike?

Tags: discussion

Sometime ago I asked a question I currently very much dislike. The question was considerably upvoted (7 upvotes currently) though and received two answers.

I would delete it but the system worries me against. I would rather prefer to dissociate my account from the post, making it anonymous. Is there a way to do this? I do not worry to lose the reps.

Comment: An upvoted question with two answers does not sound like an objectively bad question.  Are you able to clarify what you dislike about it so much that you would want no-one to know you asked it?

Comment: @postmortes what really disturbs me is that good questions of mine are often downvoted or closed, while stupid questions are getting upvoted.

Comment: That's a subjective opinion and slightly misses an important point: questions you think are stupid (because, I would guess, you've matured mathematically) might be seen as exactly what other people at a lower stage of maturity are asking themselves and looking for answers to.  I would be cautious about self-editing.  There's nothing wrong with being able to point to a question and say "oh yes, I was young and naive when I asked that!"

Answer (score 7):

You can raise a flag on that question and request dissociation. While the moderators cannot do it themselves, there is a standard procedure for asking one of the Community Managers to do that.

Presumably you can also contact SE directly and ask for that, but it seems unnecessary.

Do note, however, that this is not a mechanism for "shedding downvotes" or "erasing history". It's something that should be done only in extreme cases (so your request may end up being denied).